# Setting html controller to right side in firefox extension

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

I am creating Mozilla extension.
Here I need to set button controller right side in extension.
Here I divide XUL file to div element. I have take a main div element and inside this i have take two more inner div.
Then I have set one inner div style property float:left; and another div style property float:right. But this is not helpful for me.
Here I also set Button CSS style property float:right which is inside the div which have property float:right.

Comment: Can you please post some code samples.  I don't want to make assumptions about what you're trying to do, but generally DIV's are HTML elements, not XUL elements.  I'd love to help you and have experience with Firefox extensions, but I'm a code guy; I have to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a XUL `window`, `dialog`, `page` or `vbox`, elements are displayed from top to bottom, and if you put elements in an `<hbox>` then those are displayed left to right (except in RTL locales). But sometimes you want a right-aligned object. You then have several options:

1. The simplest version is `<hbox pack="end"><button label="right"/></hbox>`
2. If you also need an element on the left, then you can separate them with a `spacer`, like this: `<hbox><button label="left"/><spacer flex="1"/><button label="right"/></hbox>`
3. Alternatively you can also use `<vbox align="end"><button label="right"/></vbox>` which works better if you need a `radio`, `checkbox`, `label` or `description` element to be able to wrap.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Dad you tried to use dir="rtl" this one can be applied to the document or the element .... 
You can also specify the language... like it's exist on the HTML Specification... 
http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/dirlang.html

For Example

```
<Q lang="he" dir="rtl">...a Hebrew quotation...</Q>
```